# How to turn vertex / edge / face on on edit mode

Tags: edit-mode, vertices, faces, edges

I came across with a silly problem which I accidently typed a button that made vertex/edge/face dessapear on edit mode.

So I have no idea how to turn them on again.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### You might have turned off Show Overlays.

It's this button in the topbar (<kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>Z</kbd> also works):

[image: topbar in Blender]

Comment: Gotcha, Thank you!

Comment: @tet If my answer solved your problem, don't forget to accept it (checkmark near the top) so everyone knows the problem is solved.

Answer (score 2):

Alt + Shift + Z toggles Show Overlays, which shows/hides the wireframe.
Before:
[image: Before using the shortcut.]

After:
[image: After using the shortcut.]

Comment: Oh I get it, thanks so much!